# Diese Gleichung hat nichttriviale Lösungen. Oder nicht triviale Lösungen? Oder nicht-triviale Lösungen?

Tags: compound, negation, mathematics, hyphenation, compound-adjective

> Betrachten wir die Differenzialgleichung '=. Die triviale Lösung davon ist die Nullfunktion.

Nun, wie geht's weiter?

- Diese Gleichung hat auch nichttriviale Lösungen, etwa  ↦ 2ˣ.
- Diese Gleichung hat auch nicht triviale Lösungen, etwa  ↦ 2ˣ.
- Diese Gleichung hat auch nicht-triviale Lösungen, etwa  ↦ 2ˣ.

Und das Wichtigste: Warum?

Answer (score 2):

> Diese Gleichung hat eine nichttriviale Lösung.

Das ist die Benutzung des Fachterminus "nichttrivial" und bedeutet, dass es eine nichttriviale Lösung gibt, für die wir uns interessieren. Es mag daneben noch triviale Lösungen geben, die aber an der Stelle unsere Aufmerksamkeit nicht verdienen.

> Diese Gleichung hat eine nicht triviale Lösung.

Das bedeutet es gibt insgesamt eine Lösung, aber die ist nicht trivial.

> Diese Gleichung hat eine nicht-triviale Lösung.

Das bedeutet, "Ich kann kein richtiges Deutsch, will aber was sagen. Errate, was es ist!"

Die Zusammenziehung macht deutlich, dass es ein fester Begriff ist. Ähnliches findet sich bei anderen Fachbegriffen wie *nichtionisierende Strahlen*.

Comment: Schließt wirklich *Diese Gleichung hat eine nicht triviale Lösung.* dann eine zweite aus? Und @wen-auch-immer, mich würde auch der Grund des -1 interessieren.

Comment: @c.p.: Ja, abhängig von Betonung und Kontext, muss man wohl sagen. Dann würde man aber vielleicht mit Komma schreiben: "Diese Gleichung hat eine, (...) Lösung" damit das <i>eine</i> Teil einer Aufzählung von Eigenschaften wird. In didaktischen Mathebüchern wird oft konsistent "genau eine" geschrieben, wenn das ein relevanter Punkt ist.

Answer (score 1):

Eine Suche im Internet hat alle drei Schreibweisen zu Tage gefördert.

Nicht-trivial scheint mir Denglisch zu sein und von non-trivial zu kommen. Es macht im Deutschen zumindest keinen Sinn (*zwinker) hier einen Bindestrich zu setzen.

Im fachsprachlichen Kontext sehe ich vermehrt nichttrivial ([siehe z.B. hier](http://www.mathematik.net/vektoral/vak3s6.htm)). Auch [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/?q=nichttrivial) liefert dort einige (maschinell ausgesuchte) Beispiele.

Zurück zum obigen Beispiel f ' = f. Die triviale Lösung lautet f = 0. Die nichttriviale Lösung f = e^x. Für erfahrene Leute ist dies offensichtlich, manche würden auch hier von trivial sprechen. Für Anfänger im Bereich Differentialgleichungen ist die Lösung f=e^x nicht trivial (nicht leicht zu sehen / offensichtlich) wenngleich nichttrivial (nicht trivial im Sinne von f=0).

Comment: Deswegen steht das Zwinkern dort ;)

Comment: Das ist jetzt auch trivial. Wenn f eine Lösung ist, ist auch c*f eine Lösung. :D

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105906/dgl-diskussion)

Comment: *Beginner von* mit Singular klingt auch nicht wie richtiges Deutsch. *Anfänger auf dem Gebiet der Differentialgleichungen*?

Comment: Danke, bereinigt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich gehe mal von weniger gut zu gut und lasse dabei den Teil nach dem Komma absichtlich weg:

- **Diese Gleichung hat auch nicht triviale Lösungen.**
  Das passt gut in diesem Kontext:

  > Lange Zeit war unbekannt, ob diese Gleichung überhaupt Lösungen hat. Durch den Beweis von John Doe-Satoshi wissen wir endlich, dass sie gar keine Lösungen hat. Die Gleichung hat vieles nicht. Sie hat nicht Polstellen, sie hat nicht Unstetigkeitsstellen, sie hat nicht komplexe Lösungen, und sie hat auch nicht triviale Lösungen.

  Man kann des Satz also auch so interpretieren, dass man das *»nicht«* als Verneinung von *»hat«* versteht: Die eine Gleichung hat triviale Lösungen, die andere hat nicht Lösungen die man trivial nennen könnte.
- **Diese Gleichung hat auch nicht-triviale Lösungen.**
  Durch den Bindestrich ist wenigstens klar, zu welchem Wort die Verneinung gehört, und der Bindestrich ist auch erlaubt. Aber ist überflüssig, und weil das Wort ohne Bindestrich auch gut lesbar ist, sollte man darauf auch besser verzichten.
- **Diese Gleichung hat auch nichttriviale Lösungen.**
  Das ist klar und eindeutig und auch stilistisch die bessere Wahl.

Comment: Wo hast du denn her, dass ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden darf? [Diese Seite hier](https://www.riannek.de/2017/bindestrich/) behauptet ein Bindestrich wäre niemals erlaubt und auch im Duden finde ich dazu kein Beispiel.